# Vaadin 23 Flow - Spring Boot - Live Reload not working

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I recently updated my Vaadin Flow Project to the newest Version 23.0.1.
It all did great, but the LiveReload (detecting Java-FileChanges) doesnt work at all (Its detecting only CSS changes).

I created a new Spring Boot Vaadin 23 Project with Spring-Initializr to check if it's the same problem. I followed the LiveReload Section in the official Vaadin Docs, but it does'nt work at all... :(
My Console shows no errors at all..

Does someone have a similar Problem?

Console Output:

```
2022-03-21 12:28:33.379  INFO 16300 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[.....]
2022-03-21 12:28:33.814  INFO 16300 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2022-03-21 12:28:33.827  INFO 16300 --- [  restartedMain] n.b.p.s.PlatonStartupApplicationListener : Initialize Application
2022-03-21 12:28:33.828  INFO 16300 --- [  restartedMain] n.b.p.s.PlatonStartupApplicationListener : Load global catalog.

2022-03-21 12:28:33.987  INFO 16300 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-21 12:28:33.988  INFO 16300 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-21 12:28:33.992  INFO 16300 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2022-03-21 12:28:38.306  INFO 16300 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [build-status] : Compiled.
←[38;5;35m
----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------

←[0m2022-03-21 12:28:38.313  INFO 16300 --- [onPool-worker-3] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Started Webpack. Time: 9897ms
2022-03-21 12:28:38.382  INFO 16300 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : No issues found.
```

Comment: Which IDE, if any, are you using?

Comment: VSCode, with PowerShell console (mvn spring-boot:run)

Comment: Yep. I upgraded a project last week and just realized yesterday that this was happening.

Comment: Have you tried using `spring-boot-devtools` as suggested in [the docs - hotswapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.hotswapping)

Comment: In my main project spring-boot-devtools is still included. I forgot to add the dependency to my new demo project. I added the dependency and now it works in my demo. So I think it's a thing with other dependencies...

Comment: Starting the application in debug mode (in Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA) works fine for me. In Eclipse changes are applied immediately and in IntelliJ IDEA after rebuilding the sources (with the hammer icon). In a lot of cases (mostly within a single method) no application restart is necessary. But if you change method signatures or remove a class, the hot swap will fail in both IDEs.